# Is there a better way to code an if statement looking for a variable to match one of many?

Tags: c#

I need to check that a variable has one of a few different values. Currently I have code lik this:

```
if (cName == "Products" || cName == "Packages" || cName == "Contents" || cName == "Packages") 
..
if (cName == "Products" || cName == "Packages" || cName == "Contents") 
..
etc
```

It doesn't look very clean to me. Is there some simpler one line way I could do this check? Some code where I would not have to keep repeating cName?

Comment: Put them in a generic List<String> and then use the Contains(...) method

Comment: I would not recommend a switch statement for anything other than single term comparisons

Comment: @Carnotaurus: what's wrong with the switch statement? To me it looks the most readable of the answers given so far, and I'd guess that the performance is on par as well (probably better than some).

Comment: @MichaelBurr The switch syntax just "gets to me". The only time I use it as the top-level construct of a function (e.g. all paths are `return` and no statements follow it). It's funny how the little things like syntax/layout can end up effecting my [subjective] mind :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I upvoted everyone and marked the one answer I liked best.

Comment: Sure, thank you. But if you are learning C#, I would strongly recommend that you become acquainted with lambda expressions. You will be seeing them more and more.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I don't find switch statements that readable, especially if some cases involve a break where others do not. Also, I don't like literals everywhere in code, especially when case "Some-other-value" cannot be substitued for a constant, e.g., SomeOtherValue. Switch statements in C# force the use of clutter and seemingly bad practice coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also have a look at Extension Methods.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool EqualsAny(this string s, params string[] args)
    {
        return args.Contains(s);
    }

}
```

Then you could use this ike:

```
string cName = "Products";

if (cName.EqualsAny("Products", "Packages", "Contents", "Packages"))
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
switch (cName) 
{
    case "Products":
    case "Packages":
    case "Contents": // If cName is one of the above, execute code below
        ... // DO STUFF
        break;
    case "Some-other-value": // if cName is exactly Some-other-value, execute code below
        .. // DO STUFF
        break;
}
```

Comment: I hate switchs but I have to admit this is the cleanest code in this post.

Answer (score 4):

The C# way is considered to be [the lambda way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
if( System.Array.Find( new string[]{ "Products", "Packages", "Contents" }, (s) => s == cName ) != null )
..
```

Or, alternatively:

```
using System.Linq;
..
if( new string[]{ "Products", "Packages", "Contents" }.Any( s => s == cName ) )
..
```

Answer (score 3):

[`ICollection.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56.aspx) (or [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) may be worth investigating...

```
var standardCategories = new [] { "Products", "Packages", "Contents" };
if (standardCategories.Contains(cName) || cName == "Fred") {
    ...
} else if (standardCategories.Contains(cName)) {
    ...
}
```

Do be aware that this does introduce "additional overhead", f.s.v.o -- most of the time it Just Doesn't Matter, but be able to defend your decision :) As for me, I take tidier code any day and have never run into an issue with this approach, but I am also not a game developer.

(In this a particular case I'd use a *nested* if statement as the predicates seem amendable to such; the code above is just an example of usage. Note my use of "Fred" as "Packages" was being checked for ... twice.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
List<string> myMatchList = new List<string> { "Products", "Packages", "Contents" };
if ( myMatchList.Contains ( cName ) )
```

OR the "inline-version" (BEWARE it not memory-/CPU-efficient)

```
if ( (new List<string> { "Products", "Packages", "Contents" }).Contains ( cName ) )
```